# How to cache PDFDocument in ios app - swift?

Tags: swift, caching, pdfkit

I have an app with a collection view that displays thumbnails of pdf documents.  When a user taps on the thumbnail a new UIViewController is presented along with the PDFDocument.  I am trying to cache the PDFDocument so that the app does not have to download the PDFDocument from the server every time.  I have not been successful.  Iam using PDFKit to present the PDFDocument. Below is my code:

When a user taps on a thumbnail in the collection view, the following UIViewController is pushed onto the stack and displays the PDFDocument:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myPDFView: PDFView!
 let pdfCache = NSCache<NSString, PDFDocument>.init()

 func loadPDF(pdfURL: String) -> Void {

       // FIND IF PDF DOCUMENT IS ALREADY IN CACHE ON KEY 'pdfURL'
    if let documentToCache = self.pdfCache.object(forKey: pdfURL as NSString){
        self.myPDFView.document = (documentToCache as! PDFDocument)
        self.myPDFView.displayMode = .singlePage
        self.myPDFView.autoScales = true
        print("PDF FROM CACHE!")
        return
    }


 .....

    // Not found in cache.  Download pdfDocument
    Alamofire.request(pdfURL).responseData { response in

       if let data = response.data{

            DispatchQueue.main.async{

                let document = PDFDocument.init(data: data)

                // STORE PDF DOCUMENT TO CACHE
                self.pdfCache.setObject(document!, forKey: pdfURL as NSString)

                // DISPLAY PDF
                self.myPDFView.document = document
                self.myPDFView.displayMode = .singlePage
                self.myPDFView.autoScales = true
                print("PDF DOWNLOADED: \(pdfURL)")

            }
        }

    }

 }
```